# How to handle the output and input bus trans by one input in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'd like to make a simple module in verilog

The scheme is this.

```
If(en)
  A=B;
else
  B=A;
```

I want to implement to verilog without clock.

Could it be possible to implement the above logic?

## update

I want to sum of 2 inout ports.
But I'm not sure how. Would you let me know how can I make sum of 2 inout ports?

```
Module  test1(
   en,
   A,
   B,
   C
);
input en;
inout [1:0] A;
inout [1:0] B;
output [3:0] C;

...
What can I do ?
...


endmodule
```

Comment: Declaring it as `inout` and using something like `assign a=(en==1)?b:1'bz assign b=(en==0)?a:1'bz;` might help.

Comment: What is the inout port a? b?  or both?

Comment: To help you improve your question, please choose between vhdl and verilog. Not both.

Comment: @e19293001  I think a verilog. Please

Answer (score 2):

> If(en)
>     A=B;
>   else
>     B=A;

You can't sum the two inout ports `A` and `B`. `en` determines the direction. 
Consider this code:

```
assign A = (en) ? B : 1'bz;

assign B = (~en) ? A : 1'bz;
```

When `en` is low, `B` will be your output and `A` will be your input.

When `en` is high, `A` will be your output and `B` will be your input.

Your output `C` will be undefined when you assign the sum of `A` and `B` since either of the input is `1'bz`.

```
assign C = A + B; // will cause undefined behavior
```